# Hibernate envers 5.2.14 creates hibernate_sequence table even when not necessary

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I switched my Spring application from Spring Boot 1.5.x to Spring Boot 2.0. I'm using Hibernate Envers and before the switching I had `RevInfo` table to store information about the revision. The id was an autoincrement.

After the migration, Hibernate created a new `hibernate_sequence` table that is useless and not used.

I customized my RevInfo bean in this way:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(RevInfoListener.class)
public class RevInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @RevisionNumber
    private int id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    private long timestamp;

    private String username;
    private String remoteAddress;

    //omitted getters and setters
```

I avoided to extend `DefaultRevisionEntity` because I changed the `@Id` `@Generated` `value` in order to take advantage of the autoincrement (I'm using Mysql).

Despite this, using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: validate`, Hibernate requires the existence of the table even if not used. In fact with my configuration Hibernate is using my autoincrement id and the table `hibernate_sequence` is never updated.

How can I disable the creation/need of the `hibernate_sequence` table? In case I can't, could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the post.  It helped me get to the solution of eliminating the (auto) generation of the hibernate_sequence table.  My solution is below.  Notice that I used `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, which may be what you're looking for.  Anyway, here's the class I came up with.

```
@Entity(name = "EnversRevinfo")
@Table(name = "z_envers_revinfo")
@RevisionEntity( EnversRevinfo.EnversRevisionEntityListener.class)
public class EnversRevinfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @RevisionNumber
    private int id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    private long timestamp;

    @Transient
    public Date getRevisionDate() {
        return new Date( timestamp );
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public static class EnversRevisionEntityListener implements RevisionListener {

        public void newRevision( Object revisionEntity ) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            EnversRevinfo enversRevinfo =
                    ( EnversRevinfo ) revisionEntity;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ( this == o ) {
            return true;
        }
        if ( !(o instanceof EnversRevinfo) ) {
            return false;
        }

        final EnversRevinfo that = (EnversRevinfo) o;
        return id == that.id
                && timestamp == that.timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (int) (timestamp ^ (timestamp >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DefaultRevisionEntity(id = " + id
                + ", revisionDate = " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format( getRevisionDate() ) + ")";
    }
}
```